# Setting up rich text support for Rails on MySQL and Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, richtext

What does it take to store a body of formatted text that contains bold, bullet points, and different sizes in Rails?

Firstly, does the `text` field type have the ability to hold this?

If so, is it true that all I need to do is edit using a rich text editor, and display using `<pre>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `text` type is designed to store character strings.

The usual approach is to use a Javascript rich text editor which generates HTML. You save the raw HTML straight to the database, and then sanitize it when you display it. This is to prevent people from entering Javascript and other nasties into the text area that would get executed when other visitors view their input.

Rails 3 sanitizes your output by default, so *all* HTML will be escaped. You will need to call either `<%= @model.rich_text.html_safe %>` to skip this sanitizing, or (much better!) call `<%= sanitize(@model.rich_text, :tags => %w(b i p)) %>`, passing in an explicit list of allowed tags.

I have no experience with Heroku but I can't imagine it will be any different.

Comment: aside from javascript you could look into using a markdown editor like wmd-editor and a gem like bluecloth or RDiscount

Comment: Definitely - in some cases this is absolutely preferable as it avoids a lot of the issues of outputting HTML directly, and gives your users more control over their formatting. It's a bit more technical for your users though. Stackoverflow uses a WMD derivative, to give you an idea of the markdown formatting syntax.

Comment: Is this a safe list of HTML elements to whitelist? `h1 h2 h3 h4 b i p pre div ul ol li strong strike em a span img br`

Comment: I think `img` may be questionable but it depends on your audience (will some smartass be putting shock images everywhere?). The others are all fine. Note that `sanitize` will also strip all attributes, so if you want to have `img` tags you will need to allow the `src` attribute. This is another potential risk, but the sanitize method has a pretty extensive and creative test suite for catching nasties.